# PDO CRU are not functioning

Tags: php, pdo

I need your help figuring this out. I am trying to have a reserve a book functionality in my project. I don't have any error with this one but my oop functions that contains the pdo statements won't work. Particulary with the insert (values can't be inserted into the database) and update(can't update existing info from the database) part.  I don't know why this happens.

**bookReserve.php**

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include_once "../styles/header-menu-out.php";
    include_once "dbconnection.php";


    function __autoload($class){
    include_once("../main/".$class.".php");}

  $code = new codex_books();

  $sname = $_POST['sname'];
  $sid = $_POST['sid'];
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $author = $_POST['author'];
  $isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
  $publisher = $_POST['publisher'];
  $language = $_POST['language'];
  $genre = $_POST['genre'];
  $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
  $date_to_be_borrow = $_POST['date_to_be_borrow'];

  $result = $code->bookreserve($id,"book_info");

  if(isset($_POST['reserve']))
  {
      foreach($result as $row)
      {
          echo $oldstock=$row['quantity']; 
      }

      echo $newstock = $oldstock-1;

      $code->minusbookreserve($quantity, $newstock,"book_info");
      $code->insertbookreserve($sid,$sname,$title,$author,$isbn,$publisher,$language,$genre,$quantity,$date_to_be_borrow,"reserve_list");
      // echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Reserved.');window.location='bookReservelist.php';</script>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Something went wrong.');window.location='bookReservelist.php';</script>";
  }

?>
```

**codex_books.php**

```
public function minusbookreserve($quantity, $newstock, $table)
{
  $q = "UPDATE $table SET quantity = ':newstock' where book_title = ':book_title'";
  $stmt = $this->con->prepare($q);
  $stmt->execute(array(':newstock'=>$newstock, ':quantity'=>$quantity));
   if($stmt){
    return true;
    }
  else {
      return false;
  }
}

public function insertbookreserve($sid,$sname,$title,$author,$isbn,$publisher,$language,$genre,$quantity,$date_to_be_borrow,$table)
{
  $q = "INSERT INTO $table SET sid= :sid ,sname=:sname,title=:title,author=:author,isbn=:isbn,publisher=:publisher,language=:language, genre=:genre, quantity=:quantity, date_to_be_borrow=:date_to_be_borrow";
  $stmt = $this->con->prepare($q);
  $stmt->execute(array(':sid'=>$sid,':sname'=>$sname,':title'=>$title,':author'=>$author,':isbn'=>$isbn,':publisher'=>$publisher,':language'=>$language, ':genre'=>$genre,':quantity'=>$quantity,':date_to_be_borrow'=>$date_to_be_borrow));
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Remove the quotes in `SET quantity = ':newstock' where book_title = ':book_title'` to read as `SET quantity = :newstock where book_title = :book_title`

Comment: "won't work" is a bit of a vague way to explain it. *What* doesn't work? What is the desired outcome? What is happening instead? What type of error mode is PDO using?

Comment: I've done what you've said.. It gave me this error : PDOStatement::execute() [<a href='pdostatement.execute'>pdostatement.execute</a>]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: You have `newstock` and `book_title` yet you're executing the array as `newstock` and `quantity`. Something doesn't seem to balance out here. @user3345570 which is most likely the/a reason for the invalid parameter error.

Comment: @Mike Sorry about that sir. I've edited it already.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have followed MarcB answer and changed things up. But it gives me the same error.

Comment: Judging by your error message `PDOStatement::execute() [<a href='pdostatement.execute'>pdostatement.execute</a>]:` something doesn't look right to me. Where is that href coming from? @user3345570

Comment: @Fred-ii- oh.. I didn't noticed that.. I haven't place any a href on bookReserve.php either on the codex_books.php.. The a href that I have placed is only before both of that file are being executes which is <a href="bookReservelist.php"><input type="button" value="Cancel"/></a> ...

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$q = "UPDATE $table SET quantity = ':newstock' where book_title = ':book_title'";
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Where's `book_title` here?

```
$stmt->execute(array(':newstock'=>$newstock, ':quantity'=>$quantity));
```

You really MUST check return values from your DB calls for boolean `FALSE`, indicating failure. You're simply assuming everything will always succeed, which is a very BAD way of writing code.

Comment: Ah, right. I've place the corrections already but it is still giving me this error. SQLSTATE[HY093]